# How is the Code of Static IP Static Address & Get Internet Connection

Tags: android, static, console, ip, emulation

Let me introduce myself, I am Deni Yulianti and I have a problem to set IP address on android emulator (Android x-86) using console (Terminal Emulator), not using GUI.

Could you please guide me how to me to set IP static address and how the code in console in order to get internet connection?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Deni Yulianti, MSc

Comment: What problem do you have with internet connection? Every emulator has internet connection if the pc where it runs on has.

Comment: hi.. thanks for your response @greenapps. i have android x-86 version 4.3 that has no support wifi connection. I use bridged connection that resulted no internet connection. could you please guide me how is the command line using terminal emulator in order to get internet connection. besides, what is the command line for save and exit in shell script in android after i edited in /etc/init.sh. i look forward for your further information. thanks :).

Comment: Sorry, i know nothing about these things. I think you could have better explained your setup right away. I find it still unclear. Where does this emulator come from for instance?

Comment: i already setup for static IP address using command line in android x-86. oh ya. i used vmware. i can reach host ip address (PC's IP address) and IP gateway. what should i have to do in order to connect to internet? Thanks for your quick response.